# How to get Renderer of child elements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the Renderer of child elements, but in the console I get an error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
```

Code:

```
    private Renderer openBox;
    private Renderer packedBox;

    private void Start()
    {
        openBox = gameObject.transform.Find("open_box").GetComponent<Renderer>();
        packedBox = gameObject.transform.Find("packed_box").GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }
```

I am trying to run openBox.enabled=true and the same error occurs. There are multiple parent elements that have child elements with the same name.

Comment: Do you need to dynamically find the renderers, or could you serialise them through the Inspector, with the private fields decorated with [SerializeField]? But, it also sounds like getting the renderer isn't your issue, it seems like you're not actually finding the objects you want.

Comment: I need to get them without SerializeField

Comment: Read the docs, it's not recursive, or almost. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html

Answer (score 2):

I think it returns null because:

> There are multiple parent elements that have child elements with the same name.

and unity finds the first one which probably has no renderer on it.
To solve your problem, you can assign a path to the find method. For example:

[image: example]

The inner gameObject can be found like this:

```
 gameObject.transform.Find("/GameObject/open_box/open_box").GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

(Note that it starts from root)